# BAT Multiple For-loops to further filter results

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, findstr

I'm setting up a bat script that lists all postgres installations by port used (5432, 5433, etc) and lets the user choose installation. I netstat into a txt and then read it with a ***for*** loop to filter results

So far so good, but the problem is I cannot narrow the results to my liking. I would want the list generated to be like this:

```
5432
5433
5434
etc
```

This is what im using:

```
netstat -bnf -p tcp | findstr "127.0.0.1 post" > C:\anbo.txt 2>&1

for /f "usebackq tokens=2 delims=[:]" %%p in ("C:\anbo.txt") do (echo %%p )
```

This is the raw output of the "netstat":

```
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5432         127.0.0.1:51725        ESTABLISHED
 [postgres.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5432         127.0.0.1:56261        ESTABLISHED
 [postgres.exe]
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5939         127.0.0.1:49833        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49680        127.0.0.1:54677        ESTABLISHED
  TCP    127.0.0.1:49680        127.0.0.1:57445        ESTABLISHED
```

This is the netstat filtered by the ***for*** loop:

```
5432         127.0.0.1
postgres.exe
5432         127.0.0.1
postgres.exe
5939         127.0.0.1
49680        127.0.0.1
49680        127.0.0.1
```

I'm stumped on how to further filter the results. I am generating the netstat with "-b" because i want to know which ports are being used by what .exe.

Is it possible to loop ***for*** loops? A ***for*** within a ***for***, so i could further narrow down results?
If i could for example run this ***for***:

```
for /f "usebackq tokens=1 delims=. " %%s in ("F:\lop.txt") do (echo %%s)
```

Being that lop.txt has the output of the previous ***for***, i would end up with:

```
5432
postgres
5432
postgres
5939
49680
49680
```

Which would be much closer to what i want. I would just need to "somehow" filter out the results which have no "postgres" on the line below them and find a way to ignore repeated values, like not listing two 5432s. Any idea how can I accomplish this?

Comment: does `for /f "tokens=3 delims=: " %a in ('netstat') do @echo %a` do what you want?

Comment: @Stephan - I think that will work if you change the IN() clause to `('netstat -bnf -p tcp ^| findstr "127.0.0.1 post"')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET "sourcedir=U:\sourcedir"
SET "filename1=%sourcedir%\q56399294.txt"

:: remove variables starting #
FOR  /F "delims==" %%a In ('set # 2^>Nul') DO SET "%%a="

FOR /f "usebackq tokens=1,3 delims=[:] " %%p IN ("%filename1%") DO (
 IF "%%p"=="postgres.exe" (CALL :record) ELSE (SET "candidate=%%q")
)

FOR  /F "delims=#=" %%a In ('set # 2^>Nul') DO ECHO %%a

GOTO :EOF

:record
SET "#%candidate%=Y"
GOTO :eof
```

I used a file named `q56399294.txt` containing your `netstat` data for my testing.

First, clear any variables starting `#` Then analyse the `netstat` output (I've assumed every line starts with a space, as posted) and choose the first and third token (note `DELIMS` has been changed to include space). The port should be assigned to `%%q` and thence to `candidate` unless the first token is `postgres.exe`, when the port from the previous line is recorded as #*port*. Finally, report any #*port*s that are set.

Comment: This does exactly what I needed, thank you so much for the response.